# Is the phrase "collaborative skills" appropriate/correct in this context?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

If one were to suggest that they had

> "...strong documentation, collaborative, and communication skills."

My first thought is that it's a bit more awkward than saying "...collaboration...skills".

It seems that collaborative is and adjective, and a misfit for that sentence. But is this an inappropriate usage of the word "collaborative"?

Comment: "...strong documentation, collaborative and communication skills."  Just remove the comma. Means you are adept at collaborating, as well as communicating.

Comment: Thanks Little Eva. In this case, I'm not trying to craft a proper sentence, but understand why the given one is/isn't technically correct.

Comment: Because the "comma" after "collaborative" differentiates collaborative from "skills," when what you actually want is to indicate your skill in collaborating with others AND your skill at communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicions are right. `Collaborative` is an adjective, and in the phrase `collaborative skills`, it is describing the quality of the skills (in the vein of `new skills`, `useful skills` etc). Basically, you're saying your skills like to collaborate, whatever that might mean.

What you need is a [compound noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Compound_nouns). Go with `collaboration skills`.

The difference between `collaborative skills` (skills that are collaborative) and `collaboration skills` (skills of collaboration) can be compared to the difference between a `fit instructor` (instructor who is fit) and a `fitness instructor`(instructor of fitness)

Comment: Kinda frustrating someone down-voted without explaining why. The answer is articulate and seemingly accurate. Sure would be nice to know if it's wrong in some way.

Comment: Users down-vote for different reasons---some DVs are implicit criticism of the post, other DVs ... just because. I try to use DVs as criticism and re-check my post. If nothing appears wrong about the post, I figure the DV is just "because" and ignore it as something beyond my control.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks for understanding. My posts got 3 downvotes yesterday, all without explanation. I figured it's someone with a grudge. I can't imagine why, though.

Comment: @LittleEva: `And` isn't the issue here. Please explain how collaborative isn't an adjective, and why it doesn't mean what I said.

Comment: Yes, Area 51, the "and" is not the issue. The "comma" is the issue. Because the "comma" after "collaborative" differentiates collaborative from "skills," when what OP actually wants is to indicate their skill in collaborating with others AND their skill at communication. If I assert that I possess "collaborative skills" I am not indicating that my "skills like to collaborate".

Comment: @LittleEva: Ignoring the and-comma issue for a moment. _If I assert that I possess "collaborative skills" I am not indicating that my "skills like to collaborate"_ Agree to disagree. You don't mean to indicate it, but you are. The alternative is nonsensical so you'll probably be understood the way you want to be. That doesn't mean the grammar is right. I repeat: collaborative is an adjective for skills, like `new/useful/good/bad skills`. It can't mean skills of collaboration. That's like equating a `fit instructor` (instructor who is fit) to a `fitness instructor` (instructor of fitness).

Comment: @Joe: Please see my addition to the post and get back to me if something sounds incorrect.

Comment: Area 51, please accept my apologies, grammar is my weakness, so I'm having difficulty explaining myself here and I could stand some help from a good Grammarian. Check these links: collaborative (plural collaboratives) noun: 1. (management) An organized group of people or entities who collaborate towards a particular goal. See Wiktionary [collaborative](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/collaborative);

Comment: Collaborative skills are the specific ways in which students are expected to behave in order to achieve class norms. After norms have been developed, collaborative skills are assessed, prioritized and taught. See [Collaborative Skills](http://www.uvm.edu/~wfox/CollaborativeSkills.html); Find out what collaborative skills are and how to teach them to your students. See Study.com [Collaborative Skills](http://study.com/academy/lesson/collaborative-skills-definition-lesson-quiz.html)

Comment: @LittleEva: Useful links. They prove the phrase is widespread, but not that it's grammatical. I'm not eating my words.

Comment: A51, I don't want you to eat anything. I believe, however, that this usage is no longer ungrammatical. Maybe this issue would make for an interesting question.  :-)

Comment: @LittleEva: It would. Frankly, I'm kinda disappointed with the low response this question has received. It's a good question, and invites some truly good answers. Where are Mr. Lawler, Mr. Bron and Mr. Leach when you need them!

Comment: A51, indubitably. APB on the Professor, the Skipper, and @Don Bron.

Comment: @DanBron: Glad you agree. Little Eva's insistence on collaboritive skills was understandable in light of her linked pages. I had no idea `collaborative skills` is so widespread.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction Huh! Glad you @-pinged me. Hadn't read the comments before. I also didn't realize people used *collaborative skills* this way; my conception was the same as yours (the one in your answer). It still whiffs of business jargon (or I guess education jargon?) to me, so I'm not likely to adopt it myself any time soon. And Eva, I'm happy to play Gilligan if it means I get to spend a little quality time with Mary Anne.

Comment: @DanBron: I know, right. Well, that's the beauty of this site, you learn something new everyday. I learned that some unsubstantiated sources consider `collaborative` a noun in the technical sense of management (no standard dictionary does, I checked). Well, good for them. I'm sticking to what I know.

Comment: Wow, I appreciate all the extra dialog around this. In this case, I believe the author intended to use collaboration, so @Area51DetectiveFiction answered the questions squarely. While language may evolve based on how it's used, and it could be justified as valid use as a noun, I think I have the full context of what I was looking for.

Comment: Well now, I'm glad everyone is happy. "Collaborative skills" probably did emerge out of academia/corporate culture, but the usage is no longer insular and is now rather common. As for "sticking with what [you] know", Area 51, I feel confident that you will agree that "what [we] know", much like our beloved language, is evolving [even] as [we] speak [pun intended]. That said, "collaboration and communication skills" works well.

Comment: Twas I who pinged, @DanBron. I thought you'd surely be familiar with the noun usage, :-(  And, LoL, how do you know I meant Gilligan, and not Maryanne (or Ginger, for that matter)?  ;-)

Comment: @LittleEva: I agree, dictionaries are behind the coverage. But us non-natives have to stick with provable facts lest we face accusations of not knowing what we're talking about. I agree that the management sense of collaborative could be used here in the vain of `group skills`, but it still sounds highly odd to me for some reason.

Comment: @LittleEva: Thank you. It's a gift, I don't know what else to call it.  I just read a lot and watch a lot of movies, paying attention to the way things are phrased. English is kind of a hobby.

Comment: I've never thought about that. The only grammar book I own purports to be descriptive, not prescriptive. I don't frown upon people who end sentences with prepositions. But I do think there's a line between prescription and usage, and I try to stay on the right side. I do frown upon people who use `literally` to mean figuratively, even though Oxford allows it! I won't call myself an iconoclast though. You're a poet. You're allowed. I love Emily Dickinson to death and it's unthinkable for me to even pretend to qualify to judge her punctuation. That's blasphemy!

Comment: Well, I'm amazed by how "natural" your writing and sentence construction are. "Keep it up."

Comment: @LittleEva: Thanks a lot. Since you like poetry, I must mention here that Hindi/Urdu has some of the best poetry in the world. The language is ideal for writing poems in (better than English, I daresay). If you can learn one second language, choose this one.

Comment: Rabindranath Tagore. Really like what I've read of him. I'll look further.

Comment: @LittleEva: Btw, I forgot to mention yesterday that Tagore wrote not in Hindi but in [Bangla (or Bengali)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_literature), another kick-ass Indian language with lots of great poetry and literature. In fact his b'day was May 7, a few days ago. Some people celebrate that here.

Comment: @LittleEva: For Hindi poetry, might I suggest [Madhushala (The Tavern)](http://allpoetry.com/Madhushala-(The-Tavern)-) by [Harivansh Rai Bachchan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harivansh_Rai_Bachchan). It sounds infinitely better in Hindi, though.

Comment: Bravo, @LittleEva, colloquial usage trumps grammatical analysis in the mind of a native speaker. Here, the only argument for *collaboration* over *collaborative* would be stylistic parallelism: The other two end in -tion. But some American wordsmith named Ralph once said: "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, adored by little statesmen and philosophers and divines. With consistency a great soul has simply nothing to do. He may as well concern himself with his shadow on the wall." Then Ralph taught Henry, Louisa and Walt the ropes--four strong names in modern English Lit. ;-)